# Final part of the proof of $f$ is convex if and only if $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi \text { affine} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

**Let $f : \mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R} $

$f$ is convex if and only if $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi  \text { affine} \}$**

**To prove  ($\implies$) I have to follow the following steps**

(1) Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^M$ , and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $t < f (x)$ We claim that there exists an affine function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi \le f$ such that $\varphi(x) > t$;

(2) Use (1), to conclude that $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi  \text { affine} \}:=\sup S$ by proving $f \le \sup S$ and $ \sup S \le f$

**Supposing (1) is already proven, How would I prove $ (2)$?**

---

**My try:**

($f \le \sup S$) :

No clue

($ \sup S \le f$):
In two ways:

a) Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^M , \forall \varphi \in S :$
$ \varphi (x)\le f(x) \implies$ Taking the sup over all such $\varphi:$ $\sup S \le f(x)$

b)By definition of sup, $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \varphi_\varepsilon \in S, s.t.: \sup S-\varepsilon <\varphi_\varepsilon$ and by definition of $S$, $\varphi_\varepsilon \le f$, so $\sup S-\varepsilon <f$ . Taking $\varepsilon \to 0: \sup S \le f$

**What do you think? I am  unsure whether or not this is correct, because I am actually not using (1), so there must be something wrong here. What is it? and How would you proceed? I don't see the point of using the inequalities involving t as stated in (1)**

Comment: You can strictly separate $\{(x,t)\}$ and the epigraph of $f$ by a hyperplane by Hanh-Banach Theorem (as in the answer I posted to your previous question). This proves (1).

Comment: You never showed $f \leq \sup S$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You'are right, I fixed that, then apparently I have two ways of proving that, and I am clueless about the other one

Comment: @some_math_guy The other way goes by $(1)$, and I proposed you a way of doing that (Hahn-Banach)

Comment: @Didier  I am not sure I am following you, we are supposing (1) is proven in whatever way. I can still use Hahn-Banach to prove $f\le \sup S $?

Comment: Also, $b)$ is false. You don't have existence of $\varphi_{\varepsilon}$ as you stated, because $\sup S$ is the **pointwise** supremum, meaning $(\sup S)(x) = \sup_{\varphi}\{\varphi(x)\}$. You can't say that $(\sup S)(x) - \varepsilon \leqslant \varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)$ for all $x$ with $\varphi_{\varepsilon}$ fixed.

Comment: @some_math_guy No. Assume $(1)$. Fix $x$, and $t$ such that $t< f(x)$. By $(1)$, there exists $\varphi$ affine such that $\varphi \leqslant f$ and $\varphi(x) > t$. This implies that $t < \varphi(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$. This being true for all $t < f(x)$, one concludes that $f(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$. This is true for all $x$, so that $f \leqslant \sup S$.

Comment: @Didier Can I then say that for a fixed x, $\exists \varphi_\varepsilon:\sup S(x)-\varepsilon\le \varphi_\varepsilon(x) ?$ and conclude from this anyway?

Comment: @some_math_guy Yes, this is right.

Comment: @Didier So I take $\varepsilon \to 0$ and this proves$ (\sup S \le f)$, right? Is a) also a correct way of showing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $(1)$, and let $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $t$ be such that $t < f(x)$.
By $(1)$, there exists $\varphi$ affine such that $t < \varphi(x)$ and $\varphi \leqslant f$.
It follows that
$$
t < \varphi(x) \leqslant \sup_{\phi \in S} \phi(x) = (\sup S)(x).
$$
Hence, we have shown that
$$
t < (\sup S)(x).
$$
This being true for all $t < f(x)$, one concludes that $f(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$.
Finally, this being true for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, one has $f \leqslant \sup S$.

Comment: I am not sure why "This being true for all $t < f(x)$, one concludes that $f(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$" is true.   I also don't see why we need that t at the left side of all the inequalities at all

Comment: @some_math_guy 1) $t<\varphi(x)$ is given by $(1)$ for free. 2) $\varphi(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$ is because $\varphi$ is affine and $\varphi \leqslant f$, so it is by definition of the supremum. 3) Just let $t \to f(x)$ to have the final inequality $f(x) \leqslant (\sup S)(x)$.

Comment: @some_math_guy To show $a \leqslant b$, it is enough to show that for all $c \leqslant a$, one has $c \leqslant b$. This is basically the idea of this proof. If you prefer, write $t = f(x) - \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon >0$, and take $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks

Comment: Is a) also a correct way of showing the reverse inequality?

Comment: @some_math_guy You're welcome. Yes, $a)$ is correct